# Referencing a style file in another project

Tags: wpf, styles

I have a style file located in a common project, and I would like to reference to it.

This doesn't seem to work:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Common;component/Controls/Style.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
```

I'm getting a XamlParseException using the code above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the Common project referenced. The issue was that the XAML file build action wasn't set to Page, I don't know why.

Also, apprently the Source should be "pack://application:,,,/Common;Component/...", the Component should be with capital C.

Comment: The build action of a file might be changed when you copy a file from one project to another.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you forgot to add a reference to your `Common` project.

To do so:

*Right-click on the YourMainProject.References -> Add Reference... -> Solution tab -> Projects -> Common.*